# Angular, getting Ng-required of checked checkbox (or radio) in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, indexing, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to validate a form with multiple radio check boxes inside ng-repeat.
How should I validate the selected option with radio button input:
Validation outside the ng-repeat works fine. For eg. when switching $index to customDish.
The problem is validation inside ng-repeat with $index.

Field Required should be shown exactly to the selected radio button inside ng-repeat loop.

Here is a plunker

[http://plnkr.co/edit/j6bswtctD0ixaQmcDrp1?p=preview][1]

Please help
Thanks in advance

```
  [1]: http://plnkr.co/edit/j6bswtctD0ixaQmcDrp1?p=preview
```

Comment: Could you please write more clear? I cannot understand what you mean.

Comment: Select one of three radio buttons from top click submit required field is showing in all showuld show just to the selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compare this with your's ng-show:

```
ng-show="submitClicked && myOrderForm.dishQuantity.$error.required && 
($parent.checkboxSelection == $index)"
```

I've added one more condition, ensuring, that error will show only for selected item.

Comment: Yes it is a right solution Thank You for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution

```
 <input ng-pattern="onlyNumbers" placeholder="quantity" ng-required="$parent.checkboxSelection === {{$index}}" name="dishQuantity{{$index}}" id="dishPrice" data-ng-model="dish.quantity" type="text" class="dish-quantity" id="dishQuantity" />
```

and span tag

```
<span class="custom-label-danger" ng-show="submitClicked && myOrderForm.dishQuantity{{$index}}.$error.required ">Field Required</span>
```

Also working :)